# Unable to access local web server

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server

I am building a local web server on CentOS. I've installed Apache and followed this passages:

[Install and Configure Apache Server on Centos 7](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/install-and-configure-apache-server-on-centos-7)

In short, I've set “ServerName”, “DocumentRoot”, “Listen” in this way:

- `ServerName chronicles.local:80`
- `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"`
- `Listen 192.168.122.68:80` (which is my virtual machine IP address)

I've appended this line to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 chronicles.local
```

and I've created a simple web page into `index.html`
in the folder `/var/www/html`.

I've done a restart of Apache. But when I try to access my website from the browser, typing `chronicles.local`, I get "Impossible to reach the server".

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Apache is listening on `192.168.122.68`
and you are trying to reach `127.0.0.1`,
you should change your host file to `192.168.122.68 chronicles.local`